# The result is 25 in this system of linear equations, right?

Tags: linear-algebra

So I came across a picture on facebook with a simple math problem. Some of the answers to it were 60, 65, 15 (alot fought this) and some thought like me, 25. This is the picture.

[image: The problem]

So how I solved it was that I present Soda as: $X$, Burger as: $Y$ and Fries as: $Z$ and than solved it as a set of linear equations.

$$ \left[
    \begin{array}{ccc|c}
      3&0&0&30\\
      1&2&0&20\\
      0&1&2&9
    \end{array}
\right]
\left[
    \begin{array}{ccc|c}
      1&0&0&10\\
      1&2&0&20\\
      0&1&2&9
    \end{array}
\right]
...
\left[
    \begin{array}{ccc|c}
      1&0&0&10\\
      0&1&0&5\\
      0&0&1&2
    \end{array}
\right]$$

Than just insert the value of $X$, $Y$ and $Z$ in the equation at the bottom.
$$5 + (2 * 10) = 25$$
This have to be correct, otherwise I Really have to rehearse my linear algebra.. The reason I ask here is just that So many people are certain that the value is 15 for some reason.

Comment: Yes it is right...25

Comment: You got it right!

Comment: You can also solve it iteratively: the first line gives soda $=30/3=10$. The second line gives burger $=(20-10)/2=5$ etc.

Comment: But it is strange that there is a multiplication-sign between the symbols. I probably would have added the numbers and failed humiliating :(

Comment: Didn't anyone get $(5+2)\cdot 10=70$ ? This would be a typical mistake

Comment: Wrong... Answer is 15.  Two fry containers in 3rd row and 1 fry container in last row.

Comment: Oops, what a diabolic trap!

Comment: Some also answered 70, almost all the answers you can imagine seems to have been suggested now in the facebook comment section.

Comment: Yes, I meant 2 per "term".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is actually 15.  Notice that there is only 1 fry container in the last row.

Comment: Some people have said a similar thing, but I do not understand the argument.. The value of the fries is 2, otherwise I can say "There is only one soda can" also..

Comment: The value of two fries is 2. The value of 1 fries should be 1.

Comment: Now I get it! Ahh I feel so stupid! :(

Comment: I blame my bad eye sight :)

Comment: Now, I understand the answer $60$ : $(5+1)\cdot 10=60$